# add nested map value like Map<String,Map<String,String>>

Tags: flutter, dart

```
var stars = new Map<String,Map<String,String>>();
  Map<String,String> xx = {
    'test' : 'test'
  };
  stars.putIfAbsent('String', xx);
```

im getting this error `the argument type Map<String,String> cant be assigned to the parameter type Map<String,String>Function()`,
i don't know what's this `Function()` at the end of the map, i know this maybe a stupid question but i really dont know where to read about it because i found nothing helpful at official dart docs . thanks in advance

Comment: As @Ovidiu as said, the parameter 'xx' should be a function and not a value. Check the docs here: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/Map/putIfAbsent.html

Comment: thanks. i just needed this peace of documentation. actually i thought there is something with map structure not with putIfAbsent. thank you again

Comment: if you found the comment helpful, don't forget to upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: i wish you have put your comment in answer i will accept it since i was looking for documentation more than a peace of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`putIfAbsent` requires the 2nd parameter to be a function, not a value. Try this code:

```
stars.putIfAbsent('String', () => xx);
```